# In Word, Remove spurious spaces following initial quotes

Tags: microsoft-word

FineReader OCR, outputting to Word, often puts a spurious space following the initial " in reported speech, and which I wish to remove. Using Find&Replace: Find " *" , however does not distinguish between the space following the initial " and that following the final one so it will also pick the string between the final " of one quote and the initial " of the next quote.

Alternative solutions are VBA (which I would have to learn) or a Perl programme (which requires considerable revision) but I would prefer not to go those routes, since at my age, the intellectual effort they would require, might not be sustainable :)

Answer (score 0):

With normal punctuation, a simple solution is to look for `[ " ]` and replace with `[ "]` (I'm using square brackets for legibility: they are *not* part of the search or replace strings, here or below), but this won't work when quotes are at the start of lines or when there are trailing blanks within the quoted text.

I have found a more general solution, but it can't be done in a single substitution:-

1. First find matching pairs of quotes with `["*"]`.
2. Then mark them with a character that is not used in the document; I have used `#` for illustration, but you can use any other character or even a character sequence.
3. Set the replacement text as `[#^&#]` and replace all (`^&` substitutes the original match string).
4. Now you can remove the leading spaces by replacing `[#" ]` with `["]`.
5. Finally remove the remaining `#` characters by replacing `[#`] with `[]`.

This will go haywire if there are any unmatched quotes.

I don't have an up-to-date version of Office, but it certainly works on older versions, and I am not aware of major changes to find/replace in later versions.

Comment: I believe that you may need to replace `[#"]` with ``["]`` after step 4 to handle any quoted strings that didn’t get a space added (or at least it would be prudent to do so).

Comment: @G-Man - Good point: I'll update my answer. I originally deleted all `#` in the final step, but decided it was safer to include the quotes in case the character was used elsewhere. I'll go back to what I tested. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thank you both. It looks like a good solution. Yes, I spotted that unmatched quotes would cause trouble. I can only hope that I catch those in the initial editing within FineReader before export to Word. Incidentally I am using W7 and Office 2007

Comment: @LawrieHodges - You can quickly step through the document using find next with the initial search string `"*"`, to check that you are matching the pairs of quotes you expect.

Comment: @AFH - That defeats the object. While I am stepping through I might just as well delete any spurious spaces as I go. That is what have been doing up to now. But, with a lengthy document it became tedious.

Comment: @LawrieHodges - I meant to step through quickly, just to make sure there are no matches spread over multiple paragraphs, which would indicate a mismatch. It would take less than a second to do this, whereas checking for an extra space, then clicking and deleting it, and finally repositioning the cursor outside the quotes again will all take several seconds.

Comment: @LawrieHodges - Perhaps a quicker though less secure check is to replace `"` with `"` and check that the number of substitutions is even.

Comment: @AFH - Thanks again. I'll look at that later. Your three substitutions work fine on a small section of the whole document and I've incorporated them into a single macro.

Comment: @AFH - In a long document if there is one mismatch, there may well be more. It there is an even number, then the check would be misleading.

Comment: @LawrieHodges - I _did_ say that it was less secure: it was precisely that instance that I was thinking of.

Comment: Tests on a small  sample were fine but on larger file they went haywire.

Comment: I'm going to have to move to OpenOffice or LibreOffice where I can try a more conventional regex